# Union Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, union

I have been getting my hands around coding in Haskell, but couldn't grasp the idea of implementing union function.
I have also found some function definition embedded inside the Haskell platform. but the problem is I need a neat and understandable way to make it work.
Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Which union function specifically?

Comment: @bheklilr union between two sets of integers. can you help?

Comment: Are you wanting actual set union?  Have you looked in `Data.Set`?  There's a `union` function that works on `Set`s.

Comment: @bheklilr, I've looked through that, but didn't help since it uses couple of haskell built-in function to get the union. what I need is the pure coding.

Comment: Union on the `Data.Set` `Set`, or of lists? On what exactly

Comment: @jozefg, the concept of the union of both implementation are the same, what I need is just a basic function definition to implement it my own way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `union :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which takes two input lists and returns a third list which contains all of the elements of each argument list, then it's defined in [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html) which is in the `base` package.

In the source it's divided into two functions, the generalized function `unionBy` which takes a custom definition of equality (a function of type equal to `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`) and then defines the one that uses the `Eq` typeclass by passing in `(==)` as a concrete implementation of equality.

```
union                   :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union                   = unionBy (==)
```

We can substitute `(==)` into the `unionBy` code, though, as Haskell lets us use equational reasoning.

```
union = unionBy (==)

-- so...

union       :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union xs ys =  xs ++ foldl (flip (deleteBy (==))) (nubBy (==) ys) xs
```

This same pattern occurs twice more in the definition of `unionBy` in `deleteBy` and `nubBy`, both of which follow the same convention. `delete` removes an element from a list and `nub` returns a list of unique elements. We'll simplify the definition again to eliminate all traces of `(==)` and simply assume that the elements `a` have `Eq` defined.

```
union xs ys = xs ++ foldl (flip delete) (nub ys) xs
```

Now the definition is perhaps more readable. The `union` of `xs` and `ys` is `xs` appended to the unique ("`nub`bed") values of `ys` which have been processed by `foldl (flip delete) _ xs`. The net result of that `foldl` is to one by one try to `delete` each element of `xs` from `(nub ys)`. What that ends up meaning is that `union xs ys` is `xs` appended to each unique element from  `ys` less those in `xs`.

---

As an aside, with this source in hand we can notice some quirky behavior of `union` such as how it treats duplicates in the first argument differently from the second argument

```
union [1,1,2] [2] == [1,1,2]
union [2] [1,1,2] == [2,1]
```

which is a bit of a letdown, a result of using `[]` to represent a `Set`-like notion of `union`. However, if we view the results using `Set.fromList` then we're fine.

```
xs, ys :: Eq a => [a]
Set.fromList (xs `union` ys) == Set.fromList xs `Set.union` Set.fromList ys
```

which also gives us another definition of `union`

```
union xs ys = Set.toList (Set.fromList xs `Set.union` Set.fromList ys)
```

---

So how does that `foldl` trick work? Let's unpack the definition of `foldl` to see, again abusing equational reasoning.

```
union xs ys = xs ++ (case xs of
  []      -> nub ys
  (x:xs') -> foldl (flip delete) (delete x (nub ys)) xs'
  )
```

which should make the trick more evident—it cycles over the elements of `xs`, deleting them one by one from `(nub ys)`.

---

While hopefully this helped to make the code in `union` a bit more clear, the real take home should be that equational reasoning is a powerful tool for dissecting Haskell code. Don't be afraid to simplify code directly by manually inlining the definition of a function.

Comment: Thanks, but I just asked for simple information. I feel like I am pretty lost right now...

Comment: @mehdix_ Intuition: delete all the elements of `xs` from `ys` then do `xs ++ stripedDownYs`. That's what union does. The deleting part is just done with a fold

Comment: @jozefg Even easier: just use (++)

Comment: @Ingo if you want elements to be unique? plus `nub $ xs ++ ys` is O(n^2) yes?

Comment: @jozefg Sure, but the proposed solution does not make the result unique, unless the first list is unique already. Hence (++) as first approximation. At the end of the day it depends on the use case whether you need something more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this `union` meets your requirements but it is rather simple.
I needed my own function to remove duplicates.

```
rmdups ls = [d|(z,d)<- zip [0..] ls,notElem d $ take z ls]
```

It does the same as any recursive function of the same purpose.

```
union l1 l2 = let l = l1 ++ l2 in rmdups l
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misinterpreted the question, but this was a post I found as I was trying to find how to write my own union function. I understand there is one built in but as someone who was trying to learn Haskell that doesn't help at all. These were the functions I wrote to make it work.

```
memberSet :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool 
memberSet x [] = False 
memberSet x (y:ys)
  | x == y = True 
  | otherwise = memberSet x ys

unionSet :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
unionSet [] [] = []
unionSet (x:xs) [] = (x:xs)
unionSet [] (y:ys) = (y:ys)
unionSet (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | memberSet y (x:xs) = unionSet (x:xs) ys
  | otherwise = y : unionSet (x:xs) ys

main = do
  print (unionSet [1,2,3] [2,5,3,4])
```

Member set checks if an element is present in a list (again I know there is a built in function to do this but I'm trying to learn). And there union set checks if the first elem of the second list is in the first list, if its not it adds it to a list and recursively calls itself. If it is in the first list, it skips that elem and recursively calls itself.

Comment: the replit link for this is https://replit.com/@rhysbw/unionSet#Main.hs

Answer (score 0):

One problem I don't think anyone has addressed is that set union and intersection must be commutative and associative (Tom Apostol *Calculus*, p. 14).

```
λ> (Data.List.union [1,1,2] [2]) == (Data.List.union [2] [1,1,2])
False
λ> import Data.Set (Set, lookupMin, lookupMax)
λ> import qualified Data.Set as Set
λ> Set.union (Set.fromList [1, 3, 5, 7]) (Set.fromList [0, 2, 4, 6])
fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
λ> Set.union (Set.fromList [0, 2, 4, 6]) (Set.fromList [1, 3, 5, 7])
fromList [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

So `Data.List` is not aware, but few more experiments would seem to demonstrate that Haskell `Data.Set` is aware. So another nail in the coffin of lists as sets, although I suppose we could kludge something further with lists.

Comment: Well, what you'd do is to say it's commutative _modulo permutations_. When using with lists-as-sets, you're implicitly treating them as a _quotient type_ in which any two lists that can be permuted into each other are equivalent.